# Can ingress controller contain default backend and rules?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have ingress controller file with rules.

I wanted to add default backend:

```
defaultBackend:
  service:
  name: nginx-errors
    port:
      number: 80
```

so I put that in `spec` before `rules`, and I click update (I am usind UI for that).
When I reopen config file there is no sign of default backend.
I have used those config files for creating default backend service and pod: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/examples/customization/custom-errors/custom-default-backend.yaml.

What might be wrong?

Comment: You mean the Ingress resource, right? If yes, have you tried deleting the same and creating a new one from scratch (with the default backend ofcourse)?

Comment: @AbinThomas I did not. Is there a difference?

Comment: An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based virtual hosting. An Ingress controller is responsible for fulfilling the Ingress, usually with a load balancer, though it may also configure your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). I would suggest to create an ingress of your own using the link above as a reference.

Comment: Which ingress controller did you use? How did you set up your cluster?